# How can I install nautilus-gksu?

Tags: installation, nautilus, nautilus-extensions

I heard about nautilus-gksu and would like to install it. Unfortunately, when I try, I get this:

```
glemi@XPS:~$ sudo apt-get install nautilus-gksu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nautilus-gksu
```

How and where can I get this package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `nautilus-gksu` has not been in the Ubuntu repositories since 12.04.

I got the below from:
http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/09/open-files-and-folders-as-root-from.html

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-gksu
```

Then restart nautilus with this command:

```
nautilus -q
```

I didn't try this myself, and don't know if there's a better repository to add than upubuntu; it's also supposed to be available from the Linux Mint repositories from my quick Google search.  If you Google for alternates, I would recommend limiting the results to the last year, to avoid obsolete references.

Comment: Excellent answer - thank you very much Borax Bob! I used the upubuntu repository and it worked right away. I wonder why they would remove such a useful package from the standard repository.

Comment: I would up-vote your answer if I had the required reputation.

Comment: I received "E: unable to locate package nautilus-gksu" on the third step.

Comment: It seems it is no more located in that repository. Could you please update your answer or comment where one can get 'gksu' from? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`nautilus-gksu` don't work anymore for a long time since version 12.04 of Ubuntu.

In replace for this use "**Nautilus Admin**" extension where is available in the official Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin
```

What it do?

Runs Nautilus As Root for any folder and for files open as root with gedit

How to use?

Inside Nautilus, Right-click on any Nautilus file/folder and then **Open as Administrator/Edit as Administrator**

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 you cannot use nautilus-gksu anymore.

Alternative way to use a gksu command is to alias it as follows:

```
function __gksufn() {
  "$1" admin://"$2"
}

export alias gksu=__gksufn
```

In this way you can open files as `gksu gedit /path/to/your/file.txt`

Comment: Thanks for this. Maybe an obvious question, but is the alias you wrote supposed to go in `~/.bashrc`? After writing it and saving I tried `gksu nautilus` in the terminal and it was unrecognized. I tried making a `.bash_aliases` file, which is accessed by `.bashrc`, and putting it in there but it still didn't work.

Comment: @EbenCowley Is important to notice that the `__gksufn()` function **must** exists in the same environment of the alias, so I advice you to put the script into the `.bash_rc` at the end of the file. Just pay attention to `export ` part, it's important to know that the export will make alias available in the current environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection. If you are behind a proxy server, configure APT from `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to use the proxy.

Then, run `sudo apt-get update` to update the sources.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Manishearth - I believe my Internet connection works just fine (otherwise I couldn't have posted this question here, right?). There is no proxy that I know of that I'm behind (if there were I wouldn't know how to configure it). I ran `sudo apt-get update` though but it didn't help. By the way, I can install other packages without problem so I doubt it has anything to do with the Internet connection or how apt is configured.

Comment: @Glemi Did `apt-get update` work or did it return an error too? If not, then I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: It seems to work like a charm - no errors. Does installing `nautilus-gksu` work on your computer?

Comment: @Glemi yes, it does