# I tried installing gksu but getting the following error.Someone help me to fix this

Tags: 14.04, gksu

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gksu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

If it doesnt solve your problem, you can try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt) link.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/314267/how-can-i-install-nautilus-gksu