# Wifi doesn't work - I'm in a loop

Tags: wireless, gksu

I just installed windows 10 and ubuntu on my computer and wifi isn't working. I read the post below:

[WiFi isn't working in new installation of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913732/wifi-isnt-working-in-new-installation-of-ubuntu)

I tried to use the given code in the post which is:

```
gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

But it said that gksu is not installed. I tried to install gksu by the code that the terminal gave me but it said it couldn't find the package. I got the error in the following post:

[I tried installing gksu but getting the following error.Someone help me to fix this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715325/i-tried-installing-gksu-but-getting-the-following-error-someone-help-me-to-fix-t/715330)

The solution in the given post wasn't helpful since I didn't have internet. I feel like I'm in a loop where I need an internet to fix this problem but I don't have any internet. Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

P.S : If it's any help my computer is ASUS TP300L.

Comment: You don't need `gksu gedit` simply to edit a configuration file - use `sudo nano` (both of which are installed by default)

Comment: @steeldriver - Thank you for the feedback. Can you explain elaborate? Do you mean I need to write
    sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
instead of gksu gedit? And then what? Shoud I continue doing the given instructions in the post?

Comment: I don't know - and frankly, neither does anyone else since "wifi isn't working" could be the result of any number of things: IMHO you should start with [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @steeldriver - I will check the link that you have written here. But I think my problem is because I need to install the driver

Comment: Please post the info requested, then we can help